# What's the difference between text-align:start and text-align:unset?

Tags: css

Are there any cases where a browser default (`unset`) would be different from `text-align:start`? I still see a rationale for supporting `text-align:start`, because it would be very sad if the opposite of `end` was `unset`, but I'm curious if the two are actually identical or not.

Edit: Ok I guess I meant `initial` not `unset`, but the question remains - what's a case where setting it to initial would yield a different alignment from setting it to start?

Comment: read this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-unset-value ...  it is applicable to all css property support `unset` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing this answer off your edit that you meant `initial` and not `unset`:

In the case of `text-align`, as far as I know all elements currently present in HTML default to `start` as their initial value (or equivalent behavior in browsers where the actual `start` keyword is not supported, see [text-align § Specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align#Specifications)), so using `text-align:start` will basically always give the same result as `text-align:initial`, assuming you are working with a browser that supports `start`.

If in the future there is ever a newly implemented HTML element or browser that for some reason defaults things to a `text-align` value of something other than `start`, `text-align:initial` would behave accordingly on that element and I would no longer be able to make the blanket statement that all elements default to `start`.

Also, in a technical sense `start` and `initial` are not identical, because `initial` is a global value that can be used for all CSS properties to revert them to their default values, so it really isn't the opposite of *anything*. Even though functionally the result may imply it is, for this reason it would also be technically incorrect to say that `initial` is the opposite of `end`.

See also:

- [initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)
- [text-align § Specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align#Specifications)

Answer (score 3):

To clarify, `unset` does not simply set the browser default on the CSS property.  In fact:

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if it
>   inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not.

Using `unset` with the expectation that it will take the browser default could cause you some issues because it may not necessarily take the default.

With regards to `text-align`, `start` is part of the current working draft and, therefore, although implemented in some browsers may not be fully adopted.  It is not guaranteed to make it into the full specification.

`start` is not the '*browser default*'. From the spec:

> The same as left if direction is left-to-right and right if direction
>   is right-to-left.

If you wish to *reset* a property to it's default value, use `initial`:

> The initial CSS keyword applies the initial (or default) value of a
>   property to an element.

In conclusion, and in answer to your question, `text-align: start` and `text-align: unset` are definitely **not** identical.

References:

- [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)
- [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)
- [initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

**Edit following OP comment**

You have asked whether setting the `text-align` value to `initial` would cause it to behave the same as `start` (which you believe is the default).

`start` is not the default value of `text-align`. In LtR environemnts, `left` is, and in RtL environments, `right` is.  Although the outcome of the default behaviour matches having a setting of `start`, it is not the same.

Furthermore, as `start` is still in the draft specification, I would not recommend relying on it.  If the default works correctly in both LtR and RtL environments, there seems little need to implement a draft property value.

Comment: Yeah I guess I meant initial and not unset, I edited my question to reflect that, thanks for the correction. But, when is a time that setting text-align as initial would give a different alignment than setting text-align as start would give? Are there times that browsers default to text being center aligned or end-aligned for whichever direction the text is? Or is it only a matter of having the extra name for the property so we aren't stuck with "the opposite of end isn't start" in this case?

Comment: in RTL text, setting `text-align` to `initial` puts it right-aligned, not left-aligned (tested again just now to make sure).

Comment: @RRiver Yes I apologise that I did not clarify correctly what I meant in my answer. I meant that the default of `text-align` is not `start` as opposed to not changing between `left` or `right` depending upon the environment. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Start: The same as `left` if direction is left-to-right and `right` if direction is right-to-left.
2. Unset: The unset value is sort of a combination of initial and inherit.

There are some properties that, if not explicitly specified, will default to inherit. For example, if we set the color for an element, it applies to all child elements by default. Whereas other properties, like border, do not inherit by default.

When unset is applied to a property, it will apply either initial or inherit, depending on what the property's default behaviour is. If the property by default inherits, the inherit will be applied. Otherwise, initial will be applied.

References:

1. [Unset](https://bitsofco.de/initial-inherit-unset-and-revert/)
2. [Start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)